# Store admin page into variable

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin

I'm trying to store and admin page into a variable and sending back to an AJAX request. My code is the following, considering I'm in a class:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_dashboard', array('$this', 'get_dashboard'));

public function get_dashboard() {
    //generate the admin home page /wp-admin/index.php
    ob_start();
    include admin_url('index.php'); 
    $generate_index = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    wp_send_json( $generate_index );    
}
```

The problem is that I get the login screen as output. I'm working in a plugin enviroment. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In case something like this would ever need to somebody, I solved pinging the page with an AJAX request

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'your_url_to_ping',
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
     //something
     }
 }).done(function(data) {
     //something else with your data
 });
```

The page would be into your response `data`.